# Installed x11vnc onto Opensuse 12.3, but tightvnc says computer refuses connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, opensuse

First, let me say that I have never used linux before, so this might be super basic.

I'm just trying to get set up a remote desktop connection from my windows computer to a linux computer. I followed the instructions given at [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-run-a-remote-linux-desktop-in-windows/) website - I installed x11vnc and added a password.

Then I tried to log in using TightVNC on my windows computer with and without the port number. I got the following error message either way:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

How do I tell opensuse to let me connect?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the firewall is blocking you. For test purposes you could either turn off the firewall or open a port for a more permanent solution, if that was the problem.

Since you're using opensuse you can easily manage the firewall from yast. So just open yast, go to security and users, firewall.

here you can either stop the firewall or use the left hand panel to configure interfaces, allow services, etc.

if you click Allow Services you'll find a drop down menu. Scroll down to VNC and add the service to allow